# Is it possible to use .Net Web API access tokens as my licensing option for My client application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, auth-token

Is it possible to use .Net Web API's access tokens as my licensing option for My client application (windows desktop application)?

Comment: It depends, does your Windows Desktop Application allows .Net Web API's access tokens? :D

Comment: Yes, I can change my client application whatever way I want.